# Regex to match words of a certain length

Tags: java, regex

I would like to know the regex to match words such that the words have a maximum length. 
for eg, if a word is of maximum 10 characters in length, I would like the regex to match, but if the length exceeds 10, then the regex should not match.

I tried

```
^(\w{10})$
```

but that brings me matches only if the minimum length of the word is 10 characters. If the word is more than 10 characters, it still matches, but matches only first 10 characters.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to simply iterate over words and use `String.length()`?

Comment: Yes. This string is part of a bigger string that contains words of several formats - dates, emails, urls etc all in a tab delimited format.  I am thinking to write a composite regex to match the whole line.

Comment: I see. Since the words are delimited by tabs, isn't it possible to split them (using `String.split()` or `StringTokenizer`) and then look at each word length?

Comment: very much possible. in fact that was my thought at first but using a regex seemed straight forward then.. :)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I think you want `\b\w{1,10}\b`. The `\b` matches a word boundary.

Of course, you could also replace the `\b` and do `^\w{1,10}$`. This will match a word of at most 10 characters as long as its the only contents of the string. I think this is what you were doing before.

Since it's Java, you'll actually have to escape the backslashes: `"\\b\\w{1,10}\\b"`. You probably knew this already, but it's gotten me before.

Comment: Thanks. Im sure the escape have gotten me before as well.. :0 The expression you provided matches the 10 characters if the word is larger than 10. I do not want it to match if the word exceeds 10 characters.   Sort of opposite of \w{10,} you could say... !

Comment: @AnandHemmige: Which expression? The one with a `\b` should not match anything if there are more than 10 characters in the word. The same is true for the one ending in `$`. You should try the latter if the string is just one word.

Comment: In my VI version (gvim for Windows) I need a backslash (\\) before `{` for this to work.

Comment: What is the regex to find a word that is not certain characters length?

Answer (score 67):

```
^\w{0,10}$ # allows words of up to 10 characters.
^\w{5,}$   # allows words of more than 4 characters.
^\w{5,10}$ # allows words of between 5 and 10 characters.
```

Comment: I hoped that the first of these would work as a sort of opposite of \w{10,} but it doesnt.

Comment: `^` and `$` anchor the regex to the start and end of the string. If you want to extract submatches (words of a certain length), then you need to use `\b` word boundary anchors in their place: `\b\w{1,10}\b` will find words of length 1 to 10.

Comment: How to declare a regex of "allows words of 9 OR 12 characters"?

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh: `^(?:\w{9}|\w{12})$`

Comment: @TimPietzcker I had tried myself `^\w{9}|\w{12}$` and it didn't work LoL, turned out to be I need the capturing `( )`

Answer (score 32):

Length of characters to be matched.

```
{n,m}  n <= length <= m
{n}    length == n
{n,}   length >= n
```

And by default, the engine is greedy to match this pattern. For example, if the input is 123456789,   \d{2,5} will match 12345 which is with length 5.

If you want the engine returns when length of 2 matched, use \d{2,5}?

Comment: This was useful to me as I was looking for regex to find words greater than x.

Answer (score 8):

Even, I was looking for the same regex but I wanted to include the all special character and blank spaces too. So here is the regex for that:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\s$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]{0,10}$
```

Comment: How is this different to "^.{0,10}$"?

Answer (score 7):

### Method 1

Word boundaries would work perfectly here, such as with:

```
\b\w{3,8}\b
\b\w{2,}
\b\w{,10}\b
\b\w{5}\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/iQGArK/1/)

#### Java

Some languages such as Java and C++ are double-escape required:

```
\\b\\w{3,8}\\b
\\b\\w{2,}
\\b\\w{,10}\\b
\\b\\w{5}\\b
```

<sup>PS: `\\b\\w{,10}\\b` may not work for all languages or flavors.</sup>

#### Test 1

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){


        final String regex = "\\b\\w{3,8}\\b";
        final String string = "words with length three to eight";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output 1

```
Full match: words
Full match: with
Full match: length
Full match: three
Full match: eight
```

---

### Method 2

Another good-to-know method is to use negative lookarounds:

```
(?<!\w)\w{3,8}(?!\w)
(?<!\w)\w{2,}
(?<!\w)\w{,10}(?!\w)
(?<!\w)\w{5}(?!\w)
```

#### Java

```
(?<!\\w)\\w{3,8}(?!\\w)
(?<!\\w)\\w{2,}
(?<!\\w)\\w{,10}(?!\\w)
(?<!\\w)\\w{5}(?!\\w)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/q6MrUD/1/)

#### Test 2

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){


        final String regex = "(?<!\\w)\\w{1,10}(?!\\w)";
        final String string = "words with length three to eight";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output 2

```
Full match: words
Full match: with
Full match: length
Full match: three
Full match: to
Full match: eight
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vHKJz7/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/vHKJz7/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 1):

Simple, complete and tested java code, for finding words of certain length n:

```
int n = 10;
String regex = "\\b\\w{" + n + "}\\b";
String str = "Hello, this is a test 1234567890";
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
  words.add(matcher.group(0));
}
System.out.println(words);
```

For more explanations and different options - see other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Liked Pardeep's answer but I needed whole word bounds in a string/title that can be any messed up string an advertising dept. can think up .

```
**\b\w(**[A-Za-z0-9\s$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]{1,22}**)\b**
```

should iterate through a string ( tested notepad++ ) and get the largest group of words in the range i.e. 1,22 chars here without splitting mid word.

Here was the final command for me in python to add some LF's

```
name = re.sub(r"\b(\w[A-Za-z0-9\s$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]{1,22})\b","\\\1\\\n",name)
```

Comment: Are you providing a solution to the question at the top of this page? Or are you describing how you solved a different one?

Comment: for the question ( another way )  and it is just a variation on the answer  above it ... perhaps read through the whole page and see how we got to here ?

Comment: "the answer above it" There is no "above" here, because the display order is individually configurable and unpredictable. I get the impression that you confuse StackOverflow wiht a forum which has threads... But I only wanted to make sure that you intend this to be an answer to the only question on this page. Thanks.