# find words of length 4 using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to find words in regular expression with length 4

I am trying this but I am getting an empty list:

```
#words that have length of 4
s = input("please enter an expression: ")
print(re.findall(r'/^[a-zA-Z]{4}$/',s))
```

What is wrong with my code ?

my input is: `here we are having fun these days`

my expected output: `['here', 'days']`

my output: `[]`

Comment: By adding `^` and `$`, you're requiring that the *entire* string be a word of length 4, not finding all words within it of length 4.

Comment: Check out the regex \b operator instead of the ^ and $

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use word boundaries `\b`. When you add anchors in your regex like `^[a-zA-Z]{4}$`, this would match the lines which have only four alphabets. It won't check for each individual words. `^` asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character(*vice versa*). So it matches the start (*zero width*) of a word or end (*zero width*) of a word.

```
>>> s = "here we are having fun these days"
>>> re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{4}\b', s)
['here', 'days']
```

Comment: It may be useful to mention that `^` matches the start of the string and `$` the end to show that you needed to remove these to match substrings that are arbitrarily placed in the input.

Comment: Or you could use this `re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]{4}(?!\S)', s)` also.

Comment: I recommend reading the following post [Regex to match words of a certain length.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043820/regex-to-match-words-of-a-certain-length)

Comment: @Avinash Raj \b[a-zA-Z]{4}\b ..... works if the word is at the beginning or end ?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. yep. Because start and end was not a word character.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a (possibly) complicated [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), you can just use a list comprehension:

```
>>> s = "here we are having fun these days"
>>> [word for word in s.split() if len(word) == 4 and word.isalpha()]
['here', 'days']
>>>
```

Comment: it must be `[word for word in s.split() if len(word) == 4 and word.isalpha()]`

Comment: This is fine, but this is likely to be generally much slower than the regexp solution. The regexp is really not complicated, as far as regular expressions go (and regular expressions are too useful to not be learned).