# Only extract words with 2 characters Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

is there a way in Pandas data frame where I can extract words from a column of strings that are only of length of 2 characters?

For example:

> Singapore SG 
>   Jalan ID Indonesia
>   Malaysia MY

And the results will be

> SG ID MY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) by [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29689541) with [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['B'] = df['A'].str.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{2}\b').str.join(' ')
print (df)
                                             A         B
0  Singapore SG Jalan ID Indonesia Malaysia MY  SG ID MY
1                          Singapore SG Jalan         SG
2                        Singapore Malaysia MY        MY
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
df["short"] = df["test"].apply(lambda x: " ".join([i for i in x.split() if len(i) == 2]))
```

**Output:**

```
                                          test     short
0  Singapore SG Jalan ID Indonesia Malaysia MY  SG ID MY
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df = {'a': ['Singapore SG Jalan ID', 'SG Jalan ID Indonesia Malaysia MY'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)

                                   a
0              Singapore SG Jalan ID
1  SG Jalan ID Indonesia Malaysia MY

df['a1'] = df['a'].str.findall(r'\b\S\S\b')
```

Output:

```
                                   a            a1
0              Singapore SG Jalan ID      [SG, ID]
1  SG Jalan ID Indonesia Malaysia MY  [SG, ID, MY]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.Series.str.replace`

```
df.assign(B=df.A.str.replace('(\s*\w{3,}\s*)+', ' ').str.strip())

                                             A         B
0  Singapore SG Jalan ID Indonesia Malaysia MY  SG ID MY
1                           Singapore SG Jalan        SG
2                        Singapore Malaysia MY        MY
```