# How do I find countries where the name has between 4 and 5 letters with regex in python list?

Tags: python, string, list

How can I generate a list with regex in python for countries with 4 or 5 letters?

```
names = ['Azerbaijan', 'Zimbabwe', 'Cuba', 'Cambodia', 'Somalia','Mali', 'Belarus', "Côte d'Ivoire", 'Venezuela', 'Syria', 'Kazakhstan', 'Austria', 'Malawi', 'Romania', 'Congo (Brazzaville)']
```

I was trying to do this but it returns an empty list:

```
import re

n = [w for w in names if re.findall(r'[A-Z]{4,6},', str(names))]

print(n)

Output:
[]
```

It is an exercise that's why I can only do it with the module re.
Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Python has a native `len` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `len(w)`.

```
>>> names = ['Azerbaijan', 'Zimbabwe', 'Cuba', 'Cambodia', 'Somalia','Mali', 'Belarus', "Côte d'Ivoire", 'Venezuela', 'Syria', 'Kazakhstan', 'Austria', 'Malawi', 'Romania', 'Congo (Brazzaville)']

>>> [w for w in names if w.isalpha() and (len(w) in range(4,6))]
['Cuba', 'Mali', 'Syria']
```

But if you want to solve it with `regex` you can use `re.search` and
If maybe you have `numbers` in `list` you can use [`walrus`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) operator (`:=`) for python >= 3.8

```
names = ['1234', 'Azerbaijan', 'Cuba']
print([w for w in names if (tmp := re.search(r'[A-Za-z]{4,5}', w)) and (tmp.group(0) == w)])
# ['Cuba']
```

For python < 3.8 you can use `try/except`.

```
names = ['1234', 'Azerbaijan', 'Cuba']

res = []
for w in names:
    try :
        if re.search(r'[A-Za-z]{4,5}', w).group(0) == w:
            res.append(w)
    except AttributeError:
        continue
print(res)
# ['Cuba']
```

Comment: Why `range(4,5)` and not `[4,5]`?

Comment: @knittl, here you're right `[4,5]` is better, But how about `range(4,40)` or `[4,5,6,...37,38,39]` which is better, use `range` or use hard coding with `list`?

Comment: I'd probably go for `len >= 4 and len <= 40` :)

Comment: @knittl, OK but I prefer to short this : `len >= 4 and len <= 40` to `len in range(4, 41)` ;)

Comment: Thanks for fixing the off-by-one error with `range(4,5)`, which would only contain `4` :)

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use re then here is your answer [find words of length 4 using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689516/find-words-of-length-4-using-regular-expression)

if you dont need to use re just do
n = [name for name in names if len(name) in (4,5)]