# Match all words with a specific length

Tags: python, regex

I want to make a regex that matches all words with a specific length.
Example of the string I have: 
"I ABCDE FGH IG KLMNOPQ RS T"
I want to match all words having length less than 3 letters (In this case `I`, `IG`, `RS` and `T`).
Here are the alternatives that I made:
**Alt1:**
*Regex:* `( |^)([A-Z]{1,2})( |$)`: [Link1](https://regex101.com/r/IEncf5/1)
*Explanation:* Matching any word with a length of 2 or 1 uppercase letters that is preceded by a space or in the beginning of the string (`( |^)`) and followed by a space or at the end of the string (`( |$)`).

The problem is that I get positive match for the blank spaces which I don't want. And I don't get match for the `T`.
**Alt2:**
*Regex:* `\w{1,2}\b`: [Link2](https://regex101.com/r/0RVOqQ/1)
*Explanation:*

> match a word of at most 2 characters as long as its the only contents of the string
>   (I found it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9043828/8128190))

The problem is that I get matches of every last 2 letters from every word (`DE`, `GH` and `PQ`) which is wrong in my case.

Comment: Do you mean `(?<!\S)[A-Z]{1,2}(?!\S)`? https://regex101.com/r/ykA3r0/1

Comment: That literately does what I wanted. Would you please post an answer with some explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close! Just add a `\b` boundary to the front as well:

```
\b\w{1,2}\b
```

Matches:

```
I ABCDE FGH IG KLMNOPQ RS T
~           ~~         ~~ ~
```

Comment: Thank you it is working!

Answer (score 1):

If you have to take the whitespaces into account, you could match 1 or 2 uppercase digits and use lookarounds to assert what is directly on the left and on the right is not a non whitspace char `\S`

If the uppercase characters are surrounded by for example`$AB#` they will not be matched.

```
(?<!\S)[A-Z]{1,2}(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ykA3r0/1)